# winutils for 32 bit - throwing error in spark-sql code compilation

Tags: apache-spark

I'm compiling code written for Apache Spark-sql/Scala in Eclipse IDE. its saying the version of Winutils available in hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master\bin is not matching as I've 32 bit OS. the same code is working fine on my colleague machine who has 64 bit windows OS. looks like I need 32 bit Winutils.exe ? Please let me know from where I can get this file or some other way to resolve this issue. I tried searching for 32 bit winutils file but couldn't find it.